# Inconsistency in DFT in Python

Tags: signal-analysis, dft, continuous-signals, numpy

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 200                        # sampling rate
Ts = 1.0/Fs                      # sampling interval
t = np.arange(0, 1, Ts)            # time vector

f_f = np.arange(30, 80, 0.001)
a = np.arange(0, len(f_f), 1)
    
for i in range(len(f_f)):
    y2 = y2 +  np.sin(2 * np.pi * (f_f[i]) * t)

n = len(y2)        
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
frq = k/T               # two sides frequency range
freq = frq[range(int(n/2))]     # one side frequency range

Y = np.fft.fft(y2)/n                # fft computing and normalization
#Y = np.fft.fft(y2)
Y = Y[range(int(n/2))]
plt.plot(freq, abs(Y), 'r-')    # Fourier data 
plt.show()
```

> Here, as you may have noticed I have chosen df = 0.001 and the
> corresponding DFT is shown in the attached pic. However, while I am
> considering df = 1 instead, DFT comes out as sort of continuous square
> wave over the frequency domain of the signal (expected since amplitude
> of all the waves are equal). Why is it then getting distorted for df =
> 0.1 or smaller ? I mean why two peaks are appearing at f = 30 Hz & f = 80 Hz and not the entire band ?
>
> Even, sampling rate has been so chosen so that nyquist rate exceeds
> maximum frequency component of the pulse

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what your code is doing, but it does NOT look like a DFT.

Comment: @Hilmar I have edited the complete code now, kindly have a glimpse and let me know.